# Слова, образованные от междометий, союзов или частиц

Tags: словообразование, этимология

Как-то поднимался вопрос о происхождении слова "авоська", а какие ещё существуют слова, образованные от междометий, союзов или частиц?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) От междометий и звукоподражательных слов образуется большое количество глаголов со значением «издать звук, произнести междометие»:  ахать  (ахнуть), охать, ойкать, хихикать.

2) В некоторых случаях у этих слов развивается второе значение:

КУКОВАТЬ - бесцельно проводить время, ожидая

АУКНУЬСЯ - вызвать какие-л. неприятные последствия; отозваться:  Как аукнется, так и откликнется .

ПОНУКАТЬ - заставлять быстрее идти тягловый скот и заставлять делать что-л., торопить.

НАУСЬКИВАТЬ собак  (междометие УСЬ) и  подстрекать людей.

ЦЫКАТЬ  - останавливать кого-л., запрещать что-л. окриком "цыц"; прикрикивать с угрозой и резко одёргивать, отчитывать кого-л.

3) Реже от междометий образуются  слова  с другим значением:

БАСТА - междометие «баста»  является термином карточной игры. Итал.basta «хватит, довольно» . От междометия «баста» образовано «бастовать» ( первоначально «переставать играть»).

АХОВЫЙ   1. Разг. Плохой, скверный.  2. Невероятный, удивительный.

АЙБОЛИТ -   о добром докторе (враче или ветеринаре), по имени героя сказки "Доктор Айболит" К. И. Чуковского (1882 - 1969).

Answer (score 2):

Для глаголов образования от междометий не редкость: *ахать, охать* и т. п. Существительные встречаются реже. Вспомнились пелевинские *вау-импульс с вау-фактором* и интернет-мем *няша*, образованый от "ня" (японский аналог "мяу"), правда тут вопрос: является ли "ня" междометием в русском.

Comment: У Носова в "Незнайке" есть малыши Авоськин и Небоськин